# Why is this die rolling multiple times?

Tags: python, pygame, dice

I only want this die to roll once, but when i hit space it rolls like 50 times. What's wrong!?

```
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)
            diceRollLabel = myFont.render(str(diceRoll), 1, black)
            window.blit(diceRollLabel, (580, 35))
            print("Dice roll test", diceRoll)
            pygame.display.update()
```

Here's the code as it was originally posted:

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
pygame.display.update()
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)
    diceRollLabel = myFont.render(str(diceRoll), 1, black)
    window.blit(diceRollLabel, (580, 35))
    print("Dice roll test", diceRoll)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Are you holding the space bar down?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your post. As written, it won't run. And at least one possible way to indent this to make it run would cause exactly the problem you're seeing.

Comment: I don't think someone should have tried to fix the OP's indentation. I'm pretty sure incorrect indentation is the actual problem, so changing what he's posted hides relevant information.

Comment: I don't think it was the indentation as it would have given me a sintax error in PyCharm

Answer (score 2):

As posted, your code will just raise an `IndentationError` and refuse to run. So presumably your real code is indented differently. Most likely this way:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)
        diceRollLabel = myFont.render(str(diceRoll), 1, black)
        window.blit(diceRollLabel, (580, 35))
        print("Dice roll test", diceRoll)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Instead of checking `event.type == KEYDOWN` for each event, you're going through all of the events, then checking whether the last event seen had `event.type == KEYDOWN`. Until there's a new event, every time through the outer loop, the last event will still be the space `KEYDOWN`.

---

If this is the problem, to fix it, you just need to put the `if` inside the `for` loop. You presumably want the `update` in there as well. So:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)
            diceRollLabel = myFont.render(str(diceRoll), 1, black)
            window.blit(diceRollLabel, (580, 35))
            print("Dice roll test", diceRoll)
            pygame.display.update()
```

---

One reason many novices have indentation problems like this is that they're using an editor that allows them to mix tabs and spaces, and gives them no way to distinguish between the two, like Notepad or TextEdit. If this is the case, you really want to find almost any other editor. Also, you can run Python with the `-tt` flag, which will give you an error if you mix tabs and spaces in your code, making it easier to spot the invisible problem.